# typescript in gulp-concat file

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, gulp-concat

I have an Angular 2 application in which i wish to use gulp to concat som libary files.

My task for just that look as follows:
[image]

This produces a JS file and i reference it in my index.html: 
[image]

Now when i run this i get the following: 
[image]

and as we all know, there a no such thing as interfaces in js i must be dealing with typescript.

Can someone please tell me how to convert the typescript files in my libraries to js?

Comment: maybe you should concat only the .js files from the @angular and rxjs folders. Otherwise you might end up adding some d.ts files too in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **rxjs/**** and **@angular/**** lines in the **gulp.src** task will result in **all** the files in those folders being concatenated. That means the .ts and .d.ts files in those folders as well.

You should change those lines to include only the javascript files.

For example:

```
rxjs/**/*.js
@angular/**/*.js
```

That should result in only javascript files being included.

Comment: thanks for the quick response ! That helped on the interfaces!
Now i am however hit by another error : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export", again in my all.js
Does any of you have an idea why this can be?

Comment: I fear that might have a different answer though, would you be so kind as to ask as separate question about that? :)

Comment: @methgaard if the answer fixes your issue please mark it as such. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're concatenating your ts source files into all.js, instead of the compiled js output from that ts.

It's not clear from the given example what you are using to do this, but you may need to add gulp-typescript to your gulp pipeline.